# style not working when browsing though domain

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, iis, cloudflare

When i brows website using its ip address the style loading fine. But when i try to do it using domain name then style not working. The interesting thing is that i have checked both output html, css source for code and they are 100% same. Then why browser not showing style in domain mode?

direct ip browse- `view-source:http://22.199.66.33/`

domain browse- `view-source:https://www.ogibogi.com/`

here i checked both source output code- https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Any idea how to fix it?

Note: i am using cloudflare with domain.

Note: that this is happening after changing hosting server.

Answer (score 2):

Check the output in your browser's console. There's mixed content error.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Refer to Cloudflare KB on how to [troubleshoot mixed content error](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170476-Troubleshooting-mixed-content-errors).

An easy fix is to enable "Always Use HTTPS" and "Automatic HTTPS Rewrite".

Comment: I already have enabled  "Automatic HTTPS Rewrite" in cloudflare but the problem still happens. Please note that this is happening after changing hosting server.

Comment: Changes will not take effect if you have paused Cloudflare or turned on Development Mode.

Comment: thanks for your response but its not in developer mode also not paused. My question is is it happening for changing hosting server and ip address?

Comment: server and IP address wouldn't matter. check your codes - /content-pub and /script-pub has 301 permanent redirect to HTTP. why would you do that? Cloudflare attempt to rewrite the URI gets cancelled because of this, and the browser will block attempts from loading HTTP files if the page is loaded with HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Faiz is correct. Go to the crypto tab and set Automatic HTTPS rewrites to on. But, that will not affect stylesheets or javascript files. And, you have two missing scripts and one missing css file.

To correct those, you'll need to use a relative reference. If you're calling an asset with a full URL, like `<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" />`, you would want to change this to `<img src="//example.com/image.jpg" />`. By removing the `http:`, the browser will use whichever protocol the visitor is already using. And, on the crypto tab, if you set Always use `https` to on, that protocol will be `https`.